# Need help in a SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table structure and i want to have the stop batches.

[image: table structure]

referring the above table structure i want the output like following image

[image: required output]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text! (Not as images, or links to images.)

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly. Also, you might want to google gaps-and-islands.

Comment: Also, can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks everyone for your feedback, i'm not very much familiar with posting the question on stack overflow. please accept my apologies i posted it in incorrect way.

Comment: @PeterSmith - hey Peter, i've nothing in mind as of now on how i can achieve the desired result set. haven't tried much that i can share here.

Comment: If you want an answer you need to provide the data in a format others can use. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows, where [MACHINE_STATUS] is 'STOP', you could write a [WHERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) condition;

```
SELECT 
  MACHINE_NAME
, MACHINE_STATUS
, MACHINE_TIMEUPLOAD --Seems like there's missing some of the column name here
, STOP_REASON 
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE MACHINE_STATUS = 'STOP'
```

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2018.

Hope it helps,
Daniel.